# How to query fqdn of myself under POSIX 2018

Tags: c, posix

Issue 7 of posix removed `gethostbyname`, so I can no longer do `gethostbyname("my_hostname")` to get canonical hostname for my machine. I've tried to use `getnameinfo` instead, but given `/etc/hosts` like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 my_hostname.fqdn my_hostname
```

I'm getting back `localhost` (which makes sense). However `gethostbyname("my_hostname")` does return `my_hostname.fqdn` (at least both under musl and glibc).

Is there a reasonable replacement for my use case in issue 7 or am I out of luck on this one?

Comment: How would you define the “canonical” hostname for a machine?

Comment: What IETF calls "hostname" is just one of the names associated to a network interface... there could be hundreds (think webhosting).

Comment: @StephenKitt basically mirror behaviour of `hostname -f`; canonical hostname as described in `hosts(5)`

Comment: But `hosts(5)` defines canonical hostnames for IP addresses, not for a machine.

Answer (score 1):

From the Solaris man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
 These functions are used to obtain entries describing hosts.
 An  entry  can come from any of the sources for hosts speci-
 fied in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file.  See  nsswitch.conf(4).
 These      functions     have     been     superseded     by
 getipnodebyname(3SOCKET),   getipnodebyaddr(3SOCKET),    and
 getaddrinfo(3SOCKET),  which  provide greater portability to
 applications when multithreading is performed  or  technolo-
 gies  such  as  IPv6  are  used.  For example, the functions
 described in the following cannot be used with  applications
 targeted to work with IPv6.
```

As you see, the function `getaddrinfo()` is also in the POSIX standard and supported...

Answer (score 0):

The current POSIX-compliant way to (try to) determine the current host’s “canonical” FQDN is to call [`gethostname()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gethostname.html) to determine the configured hostname, then [`getaddrinfo()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) to determine the corresponding address information.

Ignoring errors:

```c
char buf[256];
struct addrinfo *res, *cur;
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

gethostname(buf, sizeof(buf));
getaddrinfo(buf, 0, &hints, &res);
for (cur = res; cur; cur = cur->ai_next) {
    printf("Host name: %s\n", cur->ai_canonname);
}
```

The results are highly dependent on the system and resolver configuration.